# Supporting "@mention" functionality with lexical js

Tags: lexicaljs

I am trying to use lexical js to build a text editor that supports mentions as in fb messenger. I have not been able to find many examples. I am trying to insert a div of possible auto-complete options that will show up under the text being entered. I assume this would be done with a decorator node? But I keep running into problems. Every time I try to insert it after the selected node, I get this error:

`Lexical node does not exist in active editor state. Avoid using the same node references between nested closures from editor.read/editor.update`

Here is my code snippet:

```
export class MenuNode extends DecoratorNode<ReactNode> {
  __searchText: string;

  static getType(): string {
    return 'menu';
  }

  static clone(node: MenuNode): MenuNode {
    return new MenuNode(node.__searchText, node.__key);
  }

  constructor(searchText: string, key?: string) {
    super(key);
    this.__searchText = searchText;
  }

  createDOM(): HTMLElement {
    return document.createElement('div');
  }

  updateDOM(): false {
    return false;
  }

  decorate(): ReactNode {
    return <WordOptions searchText={this.__searchText}/>;
  }
}


function onChange(editorState: EditorState, editor: LexicalEditor) {

  editor.update(() => {

    const selection = $getSelection();
    const selectedNode = (selection as RangeSelection).anchor.getNode();
    const menuNode = new MenuNode(selectedNode.getTextContent(), "results");
    $insertNodes([menuNode]);

    selectedNode.insertAfter(menuNode);
  });

//...

export default function Editor() {
  const initialConfig = {
    namespace: 'MyEditor', 
    theme,
    editable: true,
    onError,
    nodes: [MenuNode]
  };

  return (
    <LexicalComposer initialConfig={initialConfig}>
      <PlainTextPlugin
        contentEditable={<ContentEditable />}
        placeholder={<div>Enter some text...</div>}
        ErrorBoundary={LexicalErrorBoundary}
      />
      <OnChangePlugin onChange={onChange} />
      <HistoryPlugin />
      <MyCustomAutoFocusPlugin />
    </LexicalComposer>
  );
}


}
```

Is there some sample code I could see to help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The [Lexical Playground](https://playground.lexical.dev/) includes mentioning functionality with auto-complete popup. The code for the functionality is available [here](https://github.com/facebook/lexical/blob/main/packages/lexical-playground/src/plugins/MentionsPlugin/index.tsx).

Answer (score 1):

@mmurto 's answer has the example code that Lexical provides, and should be the correct answer; however, based on your current code, there's a different problem. I've ran into the same error myself and haven't found a solution yet, but the problem stems from attempting to replace a `TextNode` with a `DecoratorNode`.

If you change the class you're extending from `DecoratorNode` to `TextNode` (which will also make the `decorate` method useless), your code should work, but of course that removes the ability to render a React component in the Node.